# Windows 7 64bit, system backup hangs at 57%

Tags: windows-7-backup

Windows 7 64bit, system backup hangs at 57%

This is a newly built machine from scratch
Fresh install of all programs

I have the auto backup set to a secondary internal drive.  But when ever it fires it get to 57% with in a couple of minutes but then never goes any where from there.

This drive has over terabyte of free space.

Nothing else appears to be running when the backup starts, I have started it manually a couple of times just to be sure it isn't something with the scheduler.

The only thing i keep seeing about this issue is that it 'may' have to do with your antivirus program running.

This seems crazy to me as I can't imagine I have to turn off my A/V every time i do a backup, especially if it is a scheduled backup.

I assume I am missing something fundamental here.
Any help would be appreciated!

I use Nortons for my AV, trying to use windows built in backup since it is free, free = sucks maybe?

Comment: If you temporarily uninstall Norton, does the backup complete successfully? There are many 3rd party backup solutions that are far better in terms of features compared to the built-in one, but that doesn't mean the latter should get stuck midway.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google the phrase - windows 7 backup hangs at 57% - you will find a lot of requests on this issue. So, it leads to think this is a Microsoft problem. Microsoft blames this issue on external party software, but I used the system backup for 2 years in Windows 7 without this issue, until now. I didn´t install any software or changed any configuration; it just appeared.

The only solution that worked for me and many others is to delete the old backup and make a new one.